# Creating a List Approval Workflow that checks for conflicting dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, list-form, sharepoint-designer-workflow

Apologies if this is not the best forum, but I am new to SharePoint and was looking for advice/solutions for an 'equipment checkout' list with the following columns:

"ID" - Number
"Equipment Name" - Choice
"Requester Name" - Person or Group
"Requested Date" - Date and Time
"Return Date" - Date and Time
"Assigned Approver" - Person or Group
"Approval Status" - Flow assigned?

These columns are all required to contain information. The goal is for when an item is created, it checks the following fields: Equipment Name, Approval Status, Requested Date, Return Date.

When an item is created, it will check if the list has a matching Equipment Name, the next step is to check if the Approval status is 'pending' 'denied', or 'approved'. If the status is set to 'approved', it will then check if either the Requested Date and/or Return Date conflicts with the date range of the already approved item(s) which will send an automatic reply that the request has been denied. Otherwise, it will move forward and be set to pending approval like other items in waiting.

Through a workflow, an email notification would be sent to the requester if the item is pending approval, has been denied, or has been approved. Simultaneously, the workflow will create a task for the assigned approver who will receive an email to review the item and be notified of items pending approval that share conflicting dates. From here they can either approve or deny the request through a link in the email that will take them to a pending task.

Sorry for the big blocks of text. I may be asking a lot out of SharePoint, Designer, and Workflows, but any advice and help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To create a SharePoint list approval workflow that checks for conflicting dates, you can use Power Automate to create a cloud flow that automates the approval process. You can create a SharePoint list with the required columns, and then use Power Automate to create a flow that checks for conflicts in the requested date and return date fields. The flow can send automatic replies to the requester if the item is pending approval, has been denied, or has been approved. It can also create a task for the assigned approver who will receive an email to review the item and be notified of items pending approval that share conflicting dates. From here they can either approve or deny the request through a link in the email that will take them to a pending task.

Here are the steps to create the flow:

1. Create a SharePoint list with the required columns, including "Equipment Name", "Approval Status", "Requested Date", and "Return Date".
2. Sign in to Power Automate and select My flows in the left-side navigation pane.
3. On the top-left menu, select New flow > Automated cloud flow.
4. Give your flow a name.
5. Under Choose your flow's trigger, select When an item is created - SharePoint, and then select Create.
6. On the When an item is created card, select the Site Address and the List Name for the SharePoint list that you created earlier.
7. Select New step, and then type "condition" into the Choose an action search box.
   Select Condition from the list of actions.
8. In the Condition card, add the following condition: "Approval Status" is equal to "Approved".
9. Select Add an action, and then type "Get items" into the Choose an action search box.
10. Select SharePoint - Get items.
11. In the Get items card, select the Site Address and the List Name for the SharePoint list that you created earlier.
12. In the Filter Query field, add the following query: "Equipment Name" eq '[Equipment Name]' and "Approval Status" eq 'Approved' and (("Requested Date" ge '[Requested Date]' and "Requested Date" le '[Return Date]') or ("Return Date" ge '[Requested Date]' and "Return Date" le '[Return Date]')).
13. Select Add an action, and then type "Send an email" into the Choose an action search box.
14. Select Office 365 Outlook - Send an email.
15. In the Send an email card, add the email addresses for the requester and the assigned approver.
16. Customize the email message to include the appropriate information based on the approval status and the conflicting dates.
17. Save and test the flow.